# How to filter announcements by category, redux-toolkit?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I'm building a React app with Redux for state management. In one of my components, I'm trying to filter a list of announcements based on a selected category from Redux. However, I'm encountering an issue where the announcements are not being filtered as expected.

i have a compoenent with 8 cards, each card have a unique category and a component that displays a list announcements, each announcement have a category

example: i have a card with "red" category, so when i click on it i should display only the announcements with the "red" category

the categories are dispatched correctly, but the announcements are not fetched

help please